# Integrating Dropbox sync in android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Which version of Dropbox API should I use for android? It is V1 or V2?

Could someone provide me a sample/tutorial with integrating Dropbox in android platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **EDIT : July 2017**

> Dropbox API v1 is now deprecated so it's good that we have to migrate with
>   API v2

*Timeline*

- *June 28, 2016* : API v1 is deprecated.
- *September 28, 2016* : If you haven’t acknowledged the deprecation, new users of your app will see a warning when linking their Dropbox account.
- *March 28, 2017* : If you haven’t acknowledged the deprecation, all users who have linked their Dropbox account to your app will receive a warning email.
- *June 28, 2017* : API v1 endpoints are turned off.

As per the time line now api v1 is no longer working and api v2 is fully activate.
currently `'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.3'` is stable version.

New tutorial for Dropbox integration

1. [Standard android dropbox integration](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android)
2. [ShotDrop](https://github.com/botnetify/ShotDrop)
3. [valdio's dropbox integration example](https://github.com/valdio/Dropbox-integration-app)

Comment: But v1 is deprecated now...Why I should not  use v2?

Comment: I think  v2 is still beta version

Comment: Dropbox API v1 has *not* been officially deprecated. Dropbox API v2 itself has come out of beta, but the SDKs are still considered beta. There are official Android tutorials available for both [v1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android) and [v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

i think this will help you for integrating [Dropbox](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/10-steps-integrate-dropbox-api-android)

Answer (score 1):

V1 is deprecated but will probably work for quite a while. Anyway I would recommend using V2 because it is much easier to handle (especially with file IDs). V2 was just released, so there are not many good tutorials out there. Usually the easiest way is to do it quickly via cloudrail ([www.cloudrail.com](http://www.cloudrail.com)).